# How to copy to clipboard on android via jni?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to transfer a java code that will copy text to the clipboard on android to C, but nothing works for me. I am not quite familiar with jni and therefore I ask for help, I also did not find the source code for jni anywhere. Please help me.

Java Code:

```java
public static void setClipboard(String text){
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (adnroid.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    android.content.ClipData clip - android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied text", text);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

My attempts to write this myself caused the app to crash.

My code is in C:

```c
void setCliboard(const char *text){
    JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
    class context_cls = env->FindClass(OBFUSCATE("android/content/Context"));
    jfieldID cliepboardService_fid = env->getStaticFieldID(context_cls, OBFUSCATE("CLIPBOARD_SERVICE"), OBFUSCATE("Ljava/lang/String"));
    jmethodID getSystemService_mid = env->getMethodID(context_cls, OBFUSCATE("getSystemService"), OBFUSCATE("(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;"));
    jobject context_obj = env->GetStaticObjectField(activity)cls, currentActivity_fid);
    jobject clipboardService_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(context_obj, getSystemService_mid, (jstring)env->GetStaticObjectField(context_cls, cliepboardService_fid));

    jstring myText = env->NewStringUTF(text);
    jstring copiedText = env->NewStringUTF("Copied text");
    jclass clipData_cls = env->FindClass(OBFUSCATE("android.content.ClipData"))
    jmethodID newPLainText_mid = env->getMethodID(clipData_cls, OBFUSCATE("newPLainText"), OBFUSCATE("(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence)Landroid.content.CpliData;"));
    env->CallVoidMethod(clipboardService_obj, newPLainText_mid, newPLainText_obj);
}
```

Comment: First rule of debugging JNI code is to check every return code and especially whether an exception occurred. Right away I noticed that your FindClass call for ClipData cannot work because you used dots instead of slashes, you accidentally uppercased the L in "newPlainText", and you typod "ClipData" in your signature . This on top of many many many other typos. Please show us the actual code you tried, the crash site, and whatever JNI exceptions you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking for errors/exception/null_values, it's hard to tell you something....especially if half of variables are not defined in the piece you share with us.

However besiede many mispelling and wrong words, I see a wrong signature for "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence)Landroid.content.CpliData;" which should be "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Landroid/content/ClipData;".

Comment: getEnv is nothing special, it works fine and gets the current Env. For other methods work with it and work normally. And context_obj is a unity activity because I'm doing this for the unity game. com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer gets the currentActivity to call from the current activity. She also works fine. Thanks for the bug, I'll check it out.